# Random Permutations for MCMC

Tags: algorithm, bayesian, jags

I'm new to JAGS (Just Another Gibbs Sampler) and I was wondering if it is possible to extend it to sample from a space of random permutations?

The reason I ask is that I came across this tutorial on extending JAGS, and one fo the required functions "logDensity" has a required input as a double however to work with permutations I would need to input a double.

http://www.cidlab.com/prints/wabersich2013extending.pdf

Also I don't have to work with just JAGS, if anyone has another suggestion that would work I would appreciate any input.

Comment: I could code the sampler myself, I realize this is a simple task however, I wanted to use dclone (R library that uses R with Jags) to make the process parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the permutations are over 18 or fewer elements, you can represent a permutation as a double by computing its [lexicographic rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230266/how-to-calculate-the-lexicographical-rank-of-a-given-permutation). (It's possible to squeeze out a couple more elements by computing the rank as a 64-bit integer and then reinterpreting the bits as a double.)

Comment: Thank you I was just also looking at the Lehmer code also. I think this will work. Thank you