# How to generate and study regular graph for a non-integer average degree?

Tags: python, networkx, igraph, complex-networks

I have an undirected graph with the following attributes and I need to do some analysis on a fully random graph and a regular graph with the same attributes.

**Attributes:**

```
Number of Nodes = 37764
Number of Edges = 518151
Average Degree = 27.44153161741341
```

To study the properties of random graphs, I create them using `networkx.gnm_random_graph(37764,518151)` and performed my analysis. But I am very much confused about how to generate regular graphs using the same attributes.

I found two methods to generate regular graphs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51849313/6701627) using `networkx.random_regular_graph(k, n)` ([documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.random_regular_graph.html)) and `igraph.Graph().K_Regular(n, k)` ([documentation](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#K_Regular)), but noticed that they need the degree `k` to be an integer value.

But in my original graph, the value is a float value `27.44153161741341`. Now I cannot understand how to create a regular graph (or many graphs to give the same above-mentioned attributes when averaged) for my analysis.

**In rephrasing my question:** How to deal with the decimal part of the average degree in my case?

Language/library no bound for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

*A regular graph is a graph where each vertex has the same degree.*

It's not possible to have a regular graph with an average decimal degree because all nodes in the graph would need to have a decimal degree.

The best you can do is:

```
>>> G = nx.random_regular_graph(27, 37764)
>>> len(G.edges())
509814

# OR

>>> G = nx.random_regular_graph(28, 37764)
>>> len(G.edges())
528696
```

I guess you could try something like:

```
def perfect_avg(v_27, v_28):
    return v_27 * (1-0.44153161741341) + v_28 * (0.44153161741341)
```

where v_27 is the value for the graph with degree = 27
(and v_28 the value for the graph with degree = 28)

For example:

```
>>> nr_edges27 = len(G27.edges())
>>> nr_edges28 = len(G28.edges())
>>> perfect_avg(nr_edges27, nr_edges28)
518151.0
```

Comment: Yes, I've thought of having either 27 or 28 degrees, but wouldn't be the properties of these graphs differ by a large margin from the expected graph with original average degree?

Comment: the number of edges changes quite significantly at least. I don't know about shortest path lenght, cluster coeff, degree dist...

Comment: All other properties depend on the graph structure. I'm majorly worried about the number of edges as it will affect all properties. Please advise on this solution - I approximate the decimal part to 4 places. That becomes `0.4415 = 883/2000`, so I make 2000 graphs in which I make 883 graphs with 28 degrees and 2000-883=1117 graphs with 27 degrees? So, our average degree will be approximately the same over 2000 graphs.

Comment: Yess in that case the average degree of the 2000 graphs would be 27.4415

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and check the results, and if required add the improvements to the answer.

Comment: Np, the thing is.. Will the rest of the values simply average to the "correct" value? Won´t It take a ridiculous amount of time to calculate some of the properties to 2000 graphs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226047/discussion-between-thepunitsingh-and-willcrack).

Comment: I´ve edited the answer, see if it makes sense ;)

Comment: What did you think of my final answer? Anything missing?

Comment: I have discussed with few people in the field and they have told me that since we have to study the properties of the graph, the difference of 1 degree won't matter. So, we can take the round-off degree, which in this case is 27.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, I mean you want to study the regular graph, not the average of two graphs..

Comment: It seems like you have found the solution! Consider marking the question as answered by posting your own answer or by accepting mine.