# How do I get all possible set partition of a list with maximum size limit of each subset?

Tags: python, set, partition

Here is what I am trying to do. Given a number k and a set of numbers, I want to partition the set with elements of size not bigger than k.

Ex) lst = [1, 2, 3, 4], k=2

All possible set partition of lst is as follows. codes are in previous question below:
([Set partitions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python))

```
1 [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
2 [[1], [2, 3, 4]]
3 [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
4 [[1, 3, 4], [2]]
5 [[1], [2], [3, 4]]
6 [[1, 2, 3], [4]]
7 [[1, 4], [2, 3]]
8 [[1], [2, 3], [4]]
9 [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
10 [[1, 2, 4], [3]]
11 [[1], [2, 4], [3]]
12 [[1, 2], [3], [4]]
13 [[1, 3], [2], [4]]
14 [[1, 4], [2], [3]]
15 [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

However, the size of each element of each partition should not exceed k = 2.
All the case where any subset has more than k=2 elements should be deleted.
Therefore, the result should be as follows:

```
3 [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
5 [[1], [2], [3, 4]]
7 [[1, 4], [2, 3]]
8 [[1], [2, 3], [4]]
9 [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
11 [[1], [2, 4], [3]]
12 [[1, 2], [3], [4]]
13 [[1, 3], [2], [4]]
14 [[1, 4], [2], [3]]
15 [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Would there be an algorithm in python?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: `Would there be an algorithm..?` - Are you looking for an actual code solution or a written description of an algorithm?

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) may be of use.

Comment: Seems similar: Does [Python: Finding random k-subset partition for a given list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829748/python-finding-random-k-subset-partition-for-a-given-list) answer your question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you don't mind *generating* the unwanted partitions, can't they be excluded with a simple check of their length?

Comment: I see you numbered them. So order is important?

Answer (score 0):

Filter the result of an answer posted in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python) you provided by length. For example with `more_itertools.set_partitions` if you want to avoid technicality (not in the standard library).

```
p = [[[1, 2, 3, 4]],
[[1], [2, 3, 4]],
[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
[[1, 3, 4], [2]],
[[1], [2], [3, 4]],
[[1, 2, 3], [4]],
[[1, 4], [2, 3]],
[[1], [2, 3], [4]],
[[1, 3], [2, 4]],
[[1, 2, 4], [3]],
[[1], [2, 4], [3]],
[[1, 2], [3], [4]],
[[1, 3], [2], [4]],
[[1, 4], [2], [3]],
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]]

def filter_partition(partitions, k):
   return [p for p in partitions if all(len(block)<=k for block in p)]


print(*filter_partition(p, 2), sep='\n')
```

Output

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1], [2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 4], [2, 3]]
[[1], [2, 3], [4]]
[[1, 3], [2, 4]]
[[1], [2, 4], [3]]
[[1, 2], [3], [4]]
[[1, 3], [2], [4]]
[[1, 4], [2], [3]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Comment: I wish there was a faster way to generate those, beyond n = 13 it's quite slow...

Comment: @jokoon It is quite brute-force... so not very efficient. I haven't gotten any feedback so I haven't tried to reimplement it. At the moment I would recommend you to look at the answer of _alexis_ in the link provided in the question and "inject" the condition of the size directly in its solution

Comment: I did, but it's still pretty slow.

Comment: Mmm... just an input for a new reimplementation: I think the problem is related to Stirling Numbers of II-kind, [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). I will give it a try...

Comment: I was using set partitions to brute force a bin packing problem, so I've changed my approach and I might not need set partitions.